# How can I convert a PWCHAR into a FILETIME structure?

Tags: winapi, stl

The idea I have is to use the STL and convert a PWCHAR timestamp into a wstring, load it into a stream and use the >> operator to assign a given split into the appropriate member of the SYSTEMTIME structure and convert it with a Win32 function to a FILETIME structure.

```
VOID StringToFileTime(const PWCHAR timeString, FILETIME &ft) {
    if(NULL == timeString)
        return;

    wstring time(L"2013-May-14 20:33:13.132814");
    std::wistringstream stream(time);
    SYSTEMTIME st = {0};
    stream >> st.wYear;
    stream.ignore(1, '-');
    stream >> st.wMonth;
    stream.ignore(1, '-');
    stream >> st.wDay;
    stream.ignore(1, ' ');
    stream >> st.wHour;
    stream.ignore(1, ':');
    stream >> st.wMinute;
    stream.ignore(1, ':');
    stream >> st.wSecond;
    stream.ignore(1, '.');
    stream >> st.wMilliseconds;

    SystemTimeToFileTime(&st, &ft);
}
```

The problem I'm running into is the SYSTEMTIME structure does not get filled out after st.wYear. So the year gets set with 2013, but members after that are 0. 
Looking at the variable contents I get more confusion. The hardcoded timestamp does not appear in the wstring time variable in the debuggers variable view. Instead there is an nPOS number and errors listed for the time variable.

How can I convert the string to a FILETIME structure?

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 on Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: Try some debugging. Stack Overflow doesn't exist do perform basic debugging tasks for individuals.

Comment: Its a legit programming question. How do I x? Here is what I've done to attempt that. If its so basic David, why didn't you answer the question?

Comment: Why don't you learn how to debug? Don't you want to be able to do that?

Comment: I'm here to learn. Why are you hostile?

Comment: Would you like us to help you learn how to debug. We can do that?

Comment: The question I have is clear.

Comment: So not here to learn after all then

Comment: `stream >> st.wMonth;` tries to convert "May" in to integer, it fails. You can try to pre-process  the string and replace "May" with "5". Or maybe there is an easier way.

Comment: [std::get_time](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time).

Comment: Thank you Barmak and IInspectable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `stream >> st.wMonth` fails, because it is trying to read the string value `May` into a numeric `WORD`, which is not a supported conversion.  You are not resetting the `stream` error state, so subsequent uses of `>>` and `ignore()` also fail, thus the `SYSTEMTIME` does not get filled in after `wYear`.

If you have a C++11 compiler, you can use [`std::get_time()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) to parse `timeString`:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>  

bool StringToFileTime(LPCWSTR timeString, FILETIME &ft)
{
    SYSTEMTIME st = {0};

    std::wistringstream stream(timeString);
    std::tm tmb;

    // std::get_time() does not support reading milliseconds...
    if (!(stream >> std::get_time(&tmb, L"%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S")))
        return false;

    st.wYear = 1900 + tmb.tm_year;
    st.wMonth = tmb.tm_mon + 1;
    st.wDayOfWeek = tmb.tm_wday;
    st.wDay = tmb.tm_mday;
    st.wHour = tmb.tm_hour;
    st.wMinute = tmb.tm_min;
    st.wSecond = tmb.tm_sec;

    if (!stream.eof())
    {
        stream.ignore(1, L'.');

        // st.wMilliseconds is a 16bit WORD, so it can only go up to 65535.
        // There are only 1000 ms in a second, so 132814 is clearly not
        // expressed in milliseconds.  Is it nanoseconds? 100-nanoseconds?
        // Whatever it is, convert it to st.wMilliseconds as needed...

        int iValue;
        if (!(stream >> iValue))
            return false;

        st.wMilliseconds = ...;
    }

    return SystemTimeToFileTime(&st, &ft);
}
```

If you don't have a C++11 compiler, you can still use `std::wistringstream`, you just have to extract the values manually:

```
#include <sstream>

bool StringToFileTime(LPCWSTR timeString, FILETIME &ft)
{
    SYSTEMTIME st = {0};

    std::wistringstream stream(timeString);
    std::string sMonth;

    if (!(stream >> st.wYear)) return false;
    if (!stream.ignore(1, L'-')) return false;

    // st.wMonth is a 16bit WORD, but a month name is given instead.
    // parse it into st.wMonth as needed...
    if (!std::getline(stream, sMonth, L'-')) return false;
    st.wMonth = ...;

    if (!stream.ignore(1, L'-')) return false;
    if (!(stream >> st.wDay)) return false;
    if (!stream.ignore(1, L' ')) return false;
    if (!(stream >> st.wHour)) return false;
    if (!stream.ignore(1, L':')) return false;
    if (!(stream >> st.wMinute)) return false;
    if (!stream.ignore(1, L':')) return false;
    if (!(stream >> st.wSecond)) return false;

    if (!stream.eof())
    {
        stream.ignore(1, L'.');

        // convert to st.wMilliseconds as needed...

        int iValue;
        if (!(stream >> iValue))
            return false;

        st.wMilliseconds = ...;
    }

    return SystemTimeToFileTime(&st, &ft);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `swscanf()` instead of `std::wistringstream`:

```
bool StringToFileTime(LPCWSTR timeString, FILETIME &ft)
{
    SYSTEMTIME st = {0};
    WCHAR szMonth[12];
    int iValue = 0;

    int numRead = swscanf(timeString, L"%hu-%[^-]-%hu &hu:&hu:&hu.%d", &st.wYear, szMonth, &st.wDay, &st.wHour, &st.wMinute, st.wSecond, &iValue);

    if (numRead < 6) return false;

    // parse szMonth into st.wMonth as needed...

    if (numRead == 7)
    {
        // convert iValue into st.wMilliseconds as needed...
    }

    return SystemTimeToFileTime(&st, &ft);
}
```